# Anylogic: how to I move agents (people) to other agents (rooms)

Tags: anylogic

Noob question: Two agent populations: myPeople and myRooms.

- 5 myPeople created at startup
- 1 myRooms created at startup (myRooms has a square node containing an attractor).

I want to move the people from Source to myRoom. In the simplest form: Source->Go To myRooms->Sink. The Ped block "Go To" will only allow the user to select nodes that are in Main (I think). How do I make myPeople move to the Attractor (or node) contained in agent myRooms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the equal sign to the left of the dropdown menu for "Node:", so the field becomes a dynamic value and you will have an edit box instead of the dropdown menu (also the equal sign becomes an arrow). You can write `myRooms.nodeName` in there